# Python: How to create a new dataframe conditional sum two columns?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a data frame where each row represents a user's time spent on a unique issue for a month. I want to create a new data frame to group by user id, showing for each user, 1)how many issues they have opened and 2)how many issues they have spent more than 60 minutes, 3)dividing 2)by 1) and export the 4 columns to excel. I was able to get the total issues per person opened however having trouble getting the other ones.

Original data frame:  Issue ID,  User ID, Time Taken

Code used to get total issue opened per user:  df.groupby('User ID')['Issue ID'].nunique()

Comment: Can you Please share a sample of your dataframes ?

Comment: Hi Bendriss, Data frame looks like this: User ID:     ACF3    Issue ID:     M332    Time Taken: 55

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
import pandas as pd

DF = pd.DataFrame
S = pd.Series


def gt_60_mins_taken(df: DF) -> S:
    assert str(df["Time Taken"].dtype) == "timedelta64[ns]"
    mins_taken = df["Time Taken"].dt.total_seconds() / 60
    return mins_taken > 60


def handle_single_user(dfg: DF) -> S:
    n_uniq_issues = dfg["Issue ID"].nunique()
    n_uniq_issues_where_took_gt_60mins = dfg.loc[gt_60_mins_taken, "Issue ID"].nunique()
    frac_uniq_issues_took_gt_60mins = n_uniq_issues_where_took_gt_60mins / n_uniq_issues
    data = dict(
        n_uniq_issues=n_uniq_issues,
        n_uniq_issues_where_took_gt_60mins=n_uniq_issues_where_took_gt_60mins,
        frac_uniq_issues_took_gt_60mins=frac_uniq_issues_took_gt_60mins,
    )
    return S(data)


sample_data = {
    "User ID": [0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2],
    "Issue ID": [100, 101, 103, 101, 100, 100],
    "Time Taken": pd.to_timedelta(
        ["30 seconds", "70 minutes", "10 hours", "5 seconds", "8 minutes", "100 minutes"]
    ),
}

sample_df = DF(sample_data).astype(
    {
        "User ID": "int64",
        "Issue ID": "int64",
        "Time Taken": "timedelta64[ns]",
    }
)

output_df = (
    sample_df.groupby("User ID")
    .apply(handle_single_user)
    .reset_index()
    .astype(
        {
            "User ID": "int64",
            "n_uniq_issues": "int64",
            "n_uniq_issues_where_took_gt_60mins": "int64",
            "frac_uniq_issues_took_gt_60mins": "float64",
        }
    )
)

expected_output_df = DF(
    {
        "User ID": [0, 1, 2],
        "n_uniq_issues": [2, 1, 2],
        "n_uniq_issues_where_took_gt_60mins": [1, 1, 1],
        "frac_uniq_issues_took_gt_60mins": [0.5, 1.0, 0.5],
    }
)
pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(output_df, expected_output_df)

output_df.to_excel("/path/to/doc.xlsx")
```

Comment: Hi Austin, thanks a lot. After changing some data types, I was able to use your code. Thank you!!! One last question, if I want to run this monthly and have the report export to the next empty rows, do you know how should I do it? Anyway, thank you so much!!